# Add only one object from my array to Cart in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to add my object from my item array, only once to my cart. Right now you can add the same object several times. I have my array in a index.js file and my data comes from store (index.js).
The language Im working with is Vue3 with router.

```
<div v-if="product" class="product-details">
       

            <h3 class="text-center">{{ product.name}}</h3>
            <p class="description">{{ product.description }}</p>
            <img :src ="` ${ product.img }`"/>
            <h3 class="text-center">{{ product.price.toFixed(2)}} Euro</h3>
    
            <div class="cart-total" v-if="product_total">
            <h3>In Cart</h3>
            <h4>{{ product_total}}</h4>
                
            </div>
             <div class="button-container"> 
                 <button class="add"  @click="addToCart()"> Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>



<script>
        export default{
            data(){
                return{
                    
                }
            },

            props:['product', 'active'],
            methods: {
                addToCart() {
                    this.$store.commit('addToCart', this.product)
                }

                
            },
            computed: {
                    product_total(){
                        return this.$store.getters.productQuantity(this.product)
                    }
            }
        }

 mutations: {
    addToCart(state, product) {
      let item = state.cart.find(i => i.id === product.id)
      
      if (item){
          item.quantity++
      } else  {
        state.cart.push({...product, quantity: 1})
      }

      updateLocalStorage(state.cart)
    },
```

Comment: That looks like it *should* work, but there's still not enough context to determine the issue. It seems the `product` can never be found in your mutation, so it just adds a new copy to the cart. Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add quantity like that. because if you add extra quantity than, vue js that propery is not reacted by default. so we have to tell vue , for reactivity, so vue can make getter and setter for that object.

```
mutations: {
        addToCart(state, product) {
          ...
          
          if (item){
            item.quantity++
          } else  {
            Vue.set(item,'quantity',1)   // now vue will add getters and setters for  this key  quantity . now quantity change will automatically reflect.
          }
    
        ...
        },
```

you can refer to this wonderful article.
https://medium.com/js-dojo/reactivity-in-vue-js-and-its-pitfalls-de07a29c9407